# Transform ResultSet of native query hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables ABC, XYZ, i have taken their join on three common columns let's say P,Q,R.

Now,

I want the response of query to be the complete joined row.

```
Session hibernateSession = (Session) em.getDelegate();
StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer();
queryString.append("SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM ABC t1, XYZ t2 WHERE t1.P = t2.P AND t1.Q = t2.Q AND t1.R = t2.R");

Collection<----> results = query.list();
```

Do I need to create a new object which can store the complete join row or is there any way I can transform the result into two collections i.e. Collection<ABC> , Collection<XYZ>.

Please help me out, I am new to hibernate.

Thanks

Comment: You can do whatever you want. It's just a matter of iterating through the rows, building objects, and putting theme where you desire. Why don't you use HQL, though?

Comment: I found HQL very complicated while taking join. :( Anyways you mean to say I need to create another datatype object to store the complete row? and the return type would be something like Collection<ABCXYZ>

Comment: I mean to say that you choose what you do with the results. You'd better learn HQL and associations between objects if you want to use Hibernate. The corresponding HQL query would be nearly identical.

Comment: thanks Nizet will start doing that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `addEntity` method on query object, like this

```
    session.createSQLQuery("queryString")
              .addEntity("t1")
              .addEntity("t2")
              .list();
```

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13763

You may want to read about `ResultTransformers` which will be useful when working with native SQL queries.

Comment: then what will it return? Collection<ABC> or Collection<XYZ> ??

Comment: It will return an object having fields of both entities. However for this type of simple queries you should be using HQL.